# Python and Flask - Trying to have a function return a file content

Tags: python, file, flask, return

I am struggling to return a file content back to the user. Have a Flask code that receives a txt file from an user, then the Python function transform() is called in order to parse the infile, both codes are doing the job.

The issue is happening when I am trying to send (return) the new file (outfile) back to the user, the Flask code for that is also working OK.
But I don´t know how to have this Python transform function() "return" that file content, have tested several options already.

Following more details:

```
def transform(filename):

    with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename), "r") as infile:
        with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'file_parsed_1st.txt'), "w") as file_parsed_1st:

            p = CiscoConfParse(infile)
            ''' 
            parsing the file uploaded by the user and 
            generating the result in a new file(file_parsed_1st.txt)  
            that is working OK
            '''

    with open (os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'file_parsed_1st.txt'), "r") as file_parsed_2nd:
        with open(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'file_parsed_2nd.txt'), "w") as outfile:
            '''
            file_parsed_1st.txt is a temp file, then it creates a new file (file_parsed_2nd.txt)
            That part is also working OK, the new file (file_parsed_2nd.txt) 
            has the results I want after all the parsing;
            Now I want this new file(file_parsed_2nd.txt) to "return" to the user
            '''

    #Editing -  
    #Here is where I was having a hard time, and that now is Working OK
    #using the follwing line:

        return send_file(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'file_parsed_2nd.txt'))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do need to use the [`flask.send_file()` callable](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file) to produce a proper response, but need to pass in a filename or a file object that *isn't already closed or about to be closed*. So passing in the full path would do:

```
return send_file(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'file_parsed_2nd.txt'))
```

When you pass in a file object you cannot use the `with` statement, as it'll close the file object the moment you return from your view; it'll only be actually read when the response object is processed as a WSGI response, *outside* of your view function.

You may want to pass in a `attachment_filename` parameter if you want to suggest a filename to the browser to save the file as; it'll also help determine the mimetype. You also may want to specify the mimetype explicitly, using the `mimetype` parameter.

You could also use the [`flask.send_from_directory()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory); it does the same but takes a filename and a directory:

```
return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'file_parsed_2nd.txt')
```

The same caveat about a mimetype applies; for `.txt` the default mimetype would be `text/plain`. The function essentially joins the directory and filename (with [`flask.safe_join()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.safe_join) which applies additional safety checks to prevent breaking out of the directory using `..` constructs) and passes that on to `flask.send_file()`.

Comment: Hi Martijn Pieters, thank you very much for that. I´ve just edited the questions with new tests as you suggested.

Comment: @FabianoLima is the file closed (you are outside the `with` block) when you call `send_file()`? The file needs to be fully written, so flushed to disk, so the right size can be set on the response.

Comment: have just tested it again, the line "return send_file(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'file_parsed_2nd.txt'))" was inside the last "with block", have now put on the same level (indentation) as that and the Python transform() is now sending the file to the Flask code do the rest (the file parsed is now being downloaded to the user). Thank you very much again for your great help!